# jquery / javascript Redefine function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, redefine

Since I started this new webshop for a friend to launch, which still in progress, 
I'm using the so called "jQuery fixedScroll"..

Project online: http://www.merkversterkers.com/klanten/fragma/index.php?p=shop

Everything is fine until this..
When I'm using the scrollplugin, it defines the height of the page, which a good thing..

After pressing the "filter" button the height must be predefined causing a div that will expand, and I'm unable to do that, because the document defines the height when it's loaded..

like the "$(document).ready" function

**scrollfunction**

```
$('#scart').scrollToFixed({
   marginTop: $('.topbar').outerHeight() + 30,
   limit: get_limit(),
   zIndex: 999
});
```

**get_limit functon**

```
function get_limit(){
    var products_row = 4;

    var topbar = $(".topbar").height() + 30 
    var filterbar = $(".filterbar").height();
    var products = products_row * 206;

    if( $(".filterexpanded").css('display') == "block" ){
        var expanded = $(".filterexpanded").height(); 
    } else {
        var expanded = 0;
    }   

    var cartheight = $("#scart").height();

    var limit = topbar + filterbar + expanded + products + 130 - cartheight;

    return limit;
}
```

Can someone give me throw of some code I could try?
I would really appreciate all the help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without reading the question you should change this:

```
limit: get_limit(),
```

To this:

```
limit: get_limit,
```

Comment: hehe, no doesn't work since I'm calling a function and not a variable.. sorry mate

Comment: I tried, it usally is something like that though, you wouldn't believe the amount of `$('div').click(fun())` quesions we get

Comment: i know, thnx for the help anyway..!

Comment: @JayRuben: You can try doing a `trigger('remove')` and then rebind it with the new height

Comment: Yes!!! this helped me out..

Trigger remove and rebind will add the new height to the available space..

Thank you so much!

Comment: For anyone else looking at this question, the latest version of the plugin now accepts a function for the limit option.

Answer (score 1):

When you are trying to set a function as a value in an object you should not use the parentheses. When you do, you are basically evaluating the function and it's value will be returned instead of the actual function.

```
var myObject = {
    myFunction: funkyFunk()
};

function funkyFunc(){
    var funkierFunction(){
        // You COULD do this
    };
    return funkierFunction;
}
```

But this is what you need...

```
var myObject = {
    myFunction: funkyFunk
};

function funkyFunc(){
    // You probably want this though    
}
```

Comment: ok, seems good to me..
Based on the answer before .. however..
when I'm calling the get_limit..

it won't recognize the function, maybe some tips left?

Comment: Have you put some kind of a console.log or alert in the function to be 100% sure that it's NOT being called?

Answer (score 0):

An (untested) idea after looking at the [plugin's source](https://github.com/bigspotteddog/ScrollToFixed/blob/master/jquery-scrolltofixed.js):

```
var scrollToFixedObj = $('#scart').data("ScrollToFixed");
scrollToFixedObj.options.marginTop = get_limit();
```